# Mincut of graph by enum

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have a graph which I implemented as an adjacent matrix.
This looks like this.

```
       v1 v2 v3 v4
    v1 0  1  0  2
    v2 1  0  3  0
    v3 0  3  0  0
    v4 2  0  0  0
```

In my code the matrix is an
    int[][] Matrix;

Now I want to get the mincut of this graph by enumeration. But I dont know how to do this.
I already know some random mincut algorithm but for small graphs I want to find the mincut by enumeration like in the algorithm of Karger and Stein for graphs with Vertex < 6.
Here is pseudo code of this algo.

```
mincut() {
if(V<6)
    <return mincut by enumeration>
else
    t=1+n/sqrt(2)
    G1 = contract(G,t)
    G2 = contract(G,t)
    return min(mincut(G1),mincut(G2));
}
```

Could someone please explain me how to find the mincut by enumeration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm)

> Thus, the minimum cut problem can be solved in polynomial time by iterating over all choices of s,t\in V and solving the resulting minimum s-t cut problem using the [max-flow min-cut theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) and a polynomial time algorithm for maximum flow, such as the [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm), though this approach is not optimal. There is a deterministic algorithm for the minimum cut problem with running time O(mn+n^2\log n).[2]

The algorithm is spelled out for you here: [The Stoer-Wagner Min-cut Algorithm](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~pcp/stoer-wagner.pdf) You can find it on Page 3.