# Uniformly random with binary search

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, binary-tree

I would like to choose a random at uniform edge depending on its weight from a multigraph (weighted graph).
I would like to make this like it is described in Kargers algo.

The algo has two parts:

This is a Random-Select method.

```
From edges e1...em with weights w1...wm construct cumulative weights 
Wk=sum(wi,from=i=1,to=k).
Then choose an integer r uniformly at random from 0...Wm and use binary search to
identify the edge ei such that Wi-1 <= r < Wi.
```

And then we can use this method to find a random edge.

```
Goal is to choose an edge (u,v) with probability proportional to W(u,v).
First choose endpoint u with probability proportional to D(u) and then once u is
fixed choose a second endpoint v with probability proportional to W(u,v).
```

I have implemented the graph as an adjacent matrix.
This looks like this.

```
       v1 v2 v3 v4
    v1 0  1  0  2
    v2 1  0  3  0
    v3 0  3  0  0
    v4 2  0  0  0
```

In my code the matrix is an
    int[][] Matrix;

And I have an array with the cumulative sum of the row for each vertex.

But now I dont know how to implement this correctly in my code.

Could anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: did i get you right: you need the code for the sum of each row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mincut of graph by enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278459/mincut-of-graph-by-enum)

Comment: You already posted this, I already answered you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because I need a solution with a binary search like it is described in the Karger algo. And there I was asking for a deterministic mincut algorithm. I dont need the sum of each row. I need a random edge depending on its weight.

Answer (score 0):

heres the method:

```
public static int sumOfRow(int[][] array, int rowIndex) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i : array[rowIndex]) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

if you don't understand it, tell me and i will add some comments.